# graphql subscirption - could not connect to websocket

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm pretty new to whole graphql and trying to create subscriptions but when I try to run one of them I'm getting this error below

> Could not connect to websocket endpoint ws://localhost:3000/graphql.
> Please check if the endpoint url is correct.

Example I followed is inside this https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions and currently my code looks like this

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express')
const { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } = require('apollo-server-core')
const { PubSub } = require('graphql-subscriptions')
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws')
const { useServer } = require('graphql-ws/lib/use/ws')
const { env } = require('../config/index')
const schema = require('./schema')
const models = require('../db/models')
const getAuthUser = require('../utils/authorization')

const pubSub = new PubSub()
const app = express()
const httpServer = createServer(app)
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({ server: httpServer, path: '/graphql' })
const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer)
const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    csrfPrevention: true,
    cache: 'bounded',
    plugins: [
        // Proper shutdown for the HTTP server.
        ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),

        // Proper shutdown for the WebSocket server.
        {
            async serverWillStart() {
                return {
                    async drainServer() {
                        await serverCleanup.dispose()
                    },
                }
            },
        },
    ],
    playground: env.development,
    context: async ({ req }) => {
        const token = req.headers.authorization
        const user = getAuthUser(token)
        return { models, user, pubSub }
    },
})
server.applyMiddleware({ app })
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer)
module.exports = { server, httpServer }
```

In another file I have `httpServer.listen(port)`
Any tip or explanation why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method https://github.com/iam-hussain/gql-server/blob/master/src/providers/Engine.ts

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from "apollo-server-core";
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';

import typeDefs from "../graphql/schema/index";
import resolvers from "../graphql/resolvers/index";
import context from "../graphql/context";
import { PORT } from "./Configs";

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const serverInit = async () => {
  let app = express();

  // HTTP :: Creating HTTP server...
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  // WebSocketServer :: Creating web socket server...
  const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    port: 4000,
    path: '/graphql',
  });
  // Save the returned server's info so we can shut down this server later
  const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);
  
  // Apollo :: Creating Apollo server...
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }), {
      async serverWillStart() {
        return {
          async drainServer() {
            await serverCleanup.dispose();
          },
        };
      },
    }],
  });

  // Apollo :: Staring Apollo server...
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    path: "/graphql",
  });

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(` GraphQL ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
    return console.log(`Listening :: Server is running @ ${PORT}`);
  });

  return app;
};


serverInit();
```

Reference:

- Backend: https://github.com/iam-hussain/gql-server
- Frontend: https://github.com/iam-hussain/next-client

Comment: Do they need to use different ports(http server and web socker server)?

Comment: In this example, the web socket runs in 4000 and the GraphQL server runs in 5000. We can configure both to the same port also.